# Allow no special characters unless specified

Tags: javascript, regex, input

My issue lies in that I want to restrict all special characters from being input to my text box, apart from 2 characters:

"-" and "."

The issue lies in that the hyphen is used in the way I separate characters in my specification.
See JavaScript below

```
            domain = document.querySelector('#Domain_Input').value;
        let lettersDomain = /^[.a-zA-Z0-9-]+$/;
        if (domain == lettersDomain) {

            localStorage.setItem('Domain', domain);

            let cfmD = confirm("Did you mean to enter: \n" + domain + '?');
```

Is the only way to counteract this issue by escaping this method of prescribing characters to lettersDomain? Or is there another way to seperate the "-" that comes after the 9: "9-]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't compare string to regexp with ==, you should match string against regexp:

```
let domain = 'qweertryrtyrt';
let domainRegexp = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+$/gi;
if (domain.match(domainRegexp) !== null) {
    alert('Correct!');
} else {
    alert('Wrong!'); 
}
```

Also to include dot and dash in regexp you should use \ (slash), otherwise dot means any char.

Documentation for [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) function

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but thanks man! The match function is sure to make all my regex comparisons alot simpler and overall better.

Answer (score 1):

Omit your unwanted characters by specifying non special character's ASCII.
http://www.asciitable.com/

```
 function onKeyUp(event){
    var k = event.charCode;
    return ((k >= 65 && k <= 90) || (k >= 97 && k <= 122) || (k >= 49 && k <= 57))
    }
```

Comment: Thank you and im sure this does work,  but the method above fits much more nicely into the style of code I am doing, I did not know that you could specify ascii characters values however so this is extremely useful